How to access state_interface data in ros2_control
In ros2 control, how can we access state interface data like velocity and position, etc? For example when we want to control a robot using ros2_control, we publish data to a particular topic which is then automatically read.
For state interface is it the same, can we find its values in a particular topic?

Please consult the official documentation, especially the demos published there.

within ros2_control, data is not exchanged via ROS topics but are handled internally.
to publish data to the ROS world, there are several broadcasters available or you can write your own. to publish joint data, typically the joint_state_broadcaster is used.
ROS iron is end-of-life, consider updating to a newer distro.

